# Is there a way to delete Billing plans in paypal sdk?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

SDK/Library version: 1.13.1

Environment: Sandbox and Live

PayPal-Debug-ID values: None

Language, the language version, and OS: Python, Ubuntu

Issue description:

So I was wondering if there is a way to delete billing plans? I searched but I can only find for PHP and not for python.

I tried:

```
billing_plan.delete()
billing_plan.remove()
```

but none of them work

I used BillingPlan.find() to get the information about the plan so I could remove but I can't find a way to perform this action.

BTW if there isn't a way via the API let me know if I can do it via PayPal website.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Python SDK doesn't offer a method for this, you could read the PHP SDK's source code to find out how it's doing it, and then implement those methods, or call the Billing Plans API's HTTP methods directly: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/